# Watch a sessionStorage variable in AngularJS 1.0.7

Tags: angularjs

How can I watch a sessionStorage variable in AngularJS 1.0.7 without using any directive?

Something like:

```
$scope.$watch("sessionStorage.getItem('OfferStore_items')", function() {
    console.log("New offer");                               
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue this is a good idea, but if you *really* want..

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('OfferStore_items');
}, function() {
    console.log("New offer");                               
});
```

Comment: Because I don't like adding new watchers. I think with proper services you would not need this.

Comment: The answer didn´t work for me somehow. But I take your comment as good.

Comment: It is also important how you apply it. How do you set storage value?